# How to get value from checkbox and pass to PHP Page with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i am newbie in jquery and ajax programming. I have searched the answer about getting value from checkbox and pass it to PHP Page with AJAX, but it didn't work for me. Maybe someone can help me to get value from checkbox and pass to PHP Page so i can insert it to database. 
This is my checkbox code in HTML

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="pilihtambahan" style="margin-top: 5px;">

</fieldset>
$.ajax({
     url: host+'/skripsi3/phpmobile/kategori.php',
     data: { "id": getacara},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data, status){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
            $("#pilihkategori").append('<input type="radio" name="radiokategori" class="required" id="'+item.kategori+'" value="'+item.kategori+'" required><label for="'+item.kategori+'">'+item.kategori+'</label>').trigger("create");       
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            //output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
});
```

and this my html code to pass checkbox and other value to PHP Page

```
$("#simpansewa").click(function() {
            var checkValues = $('input[name=cektambah]:checked').map(function()
            {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

            var k = $("input[name=radiokategori]:checked").val();
            var u = user;
            var g = getacara;
            var b = $('#brandorder').val();
            var d = $('#deskorder').val();
            var s = $('#sosmedorder').val();
            var t = $('#tambahcat').val();
            dt = {user:u,acara:g,brand:b,desk:d,sosmed:s,kat:k,tambah:t,barangsewa:checkValues};
            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: host+'/skripsi3/phpmobile/preorder.php',
                    data: dt,
                    success: function (data){
                        alert('Data Pemesanan Anda Telah Masuk');
                        window.location="statustransaksi.html";

                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert('Fail');
                    }
                });
        });
```

this is my preorder.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";

$idtenant = $_GET["user"];
$idacara = $_GET["acara"];
$namabrand = $_GET["brand"];
$deskbrand = $_GET["desk"];
$sosmed = $_GET["sosmed"];
$tambahcat = $_GET["tambah"];
$kategori = $_GET["kat"];
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$tanggal = date("d M Y G:i");
$statusbayar = "belumbayar";
$sewa=$_GET['barangsewa'];



$query="INSERT INTO `preorder`(`namaorder`, `sosorder`, `deskorder`, `catatan`, `kategori`, `id_tenant`, `id_acara`, `statuspesanan`, `tanggal`,`statusbayar`,`tambahanbarang`) VALUES ('$namabrand','$sosmed','$deskbrand','$tambahcat','$kategori','$idtenant','$idacara','Waiting','$tanggal','$statusbayar','$sewa')";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
?>
```

Have a nice day!!

Comment: Didnt work means what?Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

create one form and passed it with the use of jQuery serialize() function. This function is get all the data related with the form.

**HTML Code**

```
<form id="test">
<input type="radio" class="required" id="item1" name="item" value="1"> One
<input type="radio" class="required" id="item2" name="item" value="2"> Two
<button type="button" id="btn" > Click Me </button>
</button>
</button>
    </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
var data = $( "#test" ).serialize()
});
```

All the data of the **test** form is assigned to the data variable. Now you can able to pass data variable to the php page with the ajax.